# Exibir layout apenas quando view não for carregada via ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, razor

Em meu projeto, estou desenvolvendo de forma que a aplicação funcione mesmo que o usuário esteja com o JavaScript desabilitado ou indisponível. Se o JavaScript não estiver disponível, carrego a página normalmente. Se estiver disponível, carrego algumas dessas páginas em um `modal` para que o fluxo fique mais fluído.

Para controlar o visual dessas páginas, cada view herda o layout padrão da minha aplicação através do arquivo `_viewstart.cshtml`. O que eu gostaria é que, quando a página for carregada via ajax, não seja usado esse layout, o que equivale a isso:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Como posso conseguir isso (preferencialmente sem depender de variáveis extras, sejam na URL ou via `@ViewBag`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Indicando a view master no controller

Uma forma de fazer isso é *não definir o layout na view, mas sim no controller*:

Na view elimine essa linha:

```
Layout = "_Layout.cshtml"; // elimine
```

Na sua action faça assim:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView("NomeView");
else
    return View("NomeView", "_Layout");
```

Assim, você pode usar a mesma view para ambos os tipos de request.

### Variando a view de acordo com o request

Ou então se quiser fazer isso na view mesmo:

```
Layout = this.Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

Comment: Me pareceu a melhor abordagem, tendo em vista que uso meu layout em uma `_viewstart`! Obrigado. Usei a terceira abordagem em um bloco `if` simples.

Answer (score 3):

Melhor fazer no `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView("partialView");
    else
        return View();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela participação!